# Deployment error while deploying

Tags: apex, deployment, unit-test, failing-tests

Apex class:

```
public void post(){           
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        Http http = new Http(); 
        req.setMethod('POST' ); // Method Type
        req.setEndpoint('http://www.nicomatic.com/_servicesWebDev/getCsvFromSalesforce.php'); // Server Url
       // Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf('salesforce'+:+'salesforce12345');
     String username = 'salesforce';
     String password = 'salesforce12345'; 
     Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password);
     String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' +
     EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
     req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); // Content Type
        List<order_batch__c> bcList = new List<order_batch__c>();
       bcList= [select Or_sub_po_number__c,Or_customer_PO_Number__c,Or_customerid__c,Or_Account_name__c,Or_invoiceadd1__c,Or_invoiceadd2__c,Or_invoiceadd3__c,Or_invoiceadd4__c,Or_invoiceadd5__c,Or_contact_Phone__c,Or_contact_Fax__c,Or_Subcontact_family_name__c,Or_Subcontact_first_name__c,Or_contact_Name__c,Or_contact_Email__c,Or_Carrier__c,Order_Date__c,Or_Comments__c,Order_numbering__c,Or_clientpn__c,Or_Nicomatic_p_n__c,Quantity_Ordered__c,Requested_Date__c,Discount__c,Unit_price__c,Or_Quote_number__c,currencyisocode,id from order_batch__c  where  Quote_Line_Item__r.Quote1__c= : Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id') order by Order_numbering__c];
      // system.debug(bcList);
     // String JSONString = JSON.serialize(bcList);
      //  system.debug(JSONString);
      String JSONString = '';
     for (order_batch__c order : bcList) {
     String orderJSON = '{\n' +
    ' "Or_sub_po_number__c" :"' + order.Or_sub_po_number__c + '",\n' +
    ' "Or_customer_PO_Number__c" :"' + order.Or_customer_PO_Number__c + '",\n' +
    ' "Or_customerid__c" :"' + order.Or_customerid__c + '",\n' +
    ' "Or_Account_name__c" :"' + order.Or_Account_name__c + '",\n' +
    ' "Or_invoiceadd1__c" :"' + order.Or_invoiceadd1__c + '",\n' +
    ' "Or_invoiceadd2__c" :"' + order.Or_invoiceadd2__c + '",\n' +
    ' "Or_invoiceadd3__c" :"' + order.Or_invoiceadd3__c + '",\n' +
    ' "Or_invoiceadd4__c" :"' + order.Or_invoiceadd4__c + '",\n' +
    ' "Or_invoiceadd5__c" :"' + order.Or_invoiceadd5__c + '",\n' +
    ' "Or_contact_Phone__c" :"' + order.Or_contact_Phone__c + '",\n' +
    ' "Or_contact_Fax__c" :"' + order.Or_contact_Fax__c + '",\n' +
    ' "Or_Subcontact_family_name__c" :"' + order.Or_Subcontact_family_name__c + '",\n' +
    ' "Or_Subcontact_first_name__c" :"' + order.Or_Subcontact_first_name__c + '",\n' +
    ' "Or_contact_Name__c" :"' + order.Or_contact_Name__c + '",\n' +
    ' "Or_contact_Email__c" :"' + order.Or_contact_Email__c + '",\n' +
    ' "Or_Carrier__c" :"' + order.Or_Carrier__c + '",\n' +
    ' "Order_Date__c" :"' + order.Order_Date__c + '",\n' +
    ' "Or_Comments__c" :"' + order.Or_Comments__c + '",\n' +
    ' "Order_numbering__c" :"' + order.Order_numbering__c + '",\n' +
    ' "Or_clientpn__c" :"' + order.Or_clientpn__c + '",\n' +
    ' "Or_Nicomatic_p_n__c" :"' + order.Or_Nicomatic_p_n__c + '",\n' +
    ' "Quantity_Ordered__c" :"' + order.Quantity_Ordered__c + '",\n' +
    ' "Requested_Date__c" :"' + order.Requested_Date__c + '",\n' +
    ' "Discount__c" :"' + order.Discount__c + '",\n' +
    ' "Unit_price__c" :"' + order.Unit_price__c + '",\n' +
    ' "Or_Quote_number__c" :"' + order.Or_Quote_number__c + '"' +
    '},';
      JSONString +=orderJSON ;
         }     
        req.setBody('csvcontent=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode('['+ JSONString.substring(0,JSONString.length()-1) +']', 'UTF-8' ); // Request Parameters
       try {
        system.debug( EncodingUtil.urlEncode(JSONString, 'UTF-8'));
            res = http.send(req);
            if(res.getBody() != null){
                system.debug(res.getbody()); //Parse Response
                res1=res.getbody();
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.debug('error: '+ e);
       }
}
```

Test Apex Class:

```
@IsTest
private class TestFinalorderreviw 
{

 static testmethod void TestFinalorderreviw()
 {
   Account A= new Account(Name='test', BillingCountry ='India');
  insert A;
   Contact con=new Contact();
                con.FirstName='Test';
                con.LastName='testwe';
                con.AccountId=a.id;
                con.Fax='8906745632';
                con.Phone='8906745632';
                con.Email='test@gmail.com';
                con.LastName='Jena';
                con.Primary_Contact__c=true;
                con.MailingCountry = 'India';
                try{
                    Insert con;
                }catch(DMLException de){
                    System.debug('*********cont********'+de);
                }
  Opportunity op= new opportunity(Name='test',CloseDate=date.today(),StageName='Qualification',Product_Type__c='DPI',Accountid=A.Id);
  insert op;

  Quote__c q1 = New Quote__c (Opportunity_Name__c = op.Id,Account_Name__c = A.Id);
  insert q1; 

  Quote_Line_Item__c  qll = new Quote_Line_Item__c (Name='test',Quote1__c = q1.id);
  insert qll;
order_batch__c b1 =new order_batch__c( Quantity_Ordered__c =1111,Quote_Line_Item__c = qll .id);
            insert b1;
           finalorderreview obj=new finalorderreview();
           obj.cancel1(); 
           obj.save();
           obj.post();
           obj.getob1();
 }
 }
```

> Deploy error : System.StringException: Ending position out of bounds:
>   -1  Stack Trace: Class.finalorderreview.post: line 79, column 1 Class.TestFinalorderreviw.TestFinalorderreviw: line 37, column 1

```
  req.setBody('csvcontent=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode('['+ JSONString.substring(0,JSONString.length()-1) +']', 'UTF-8' ); // Request Parameters

    obj.post();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your test:

```
PageReference pageRef = Page.YourPageName;
pageRef.getParameters().put('Id', q1.Id);
Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
```

before you create finalorderreview.

The query in the post method references:

```
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id')
```

and so your test needs to supply that value, otherwise the query will return no results and the JSONString will remain at length zero.